# webpack cannot bound: Cannot set property 'Symbol(should not be considered a local binding)' of undefined

Tags: git, reactjs, ecmascript-6, webpack

I have a weird problem in webpack or git.

I have a local repository with my project (webpack-babel-react). The bounding on my local repo is working.

Once I push changes to a remote repository and then I clone it in an other location, I cannot bundle some files.

doing `diff -r repo1 repo2` in not showing any differences between the two repositories. For this reason I suppose that git is doing his job properly.

I'm not able to understand the webpack message error:

```
ERROR in ./app/js/components/Convictions/SectorsSliders.react.js
Module build failed: TypeError: /path/app/js/components/Convictions/SectorsSliders.react.js: Cannot set property 'Symbol(should not be considered a local binding)' of undefined
    at Object.push (/path/node_modules/babel-helper-define-map/lib/index.js:96:37)
    at pushToMap (/path/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-classes/lib/vanilla.js:191:25)
    at pushMethod (/path/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-classes/lib/vanilla.js:531:10)
    at pushBody (/path/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-classes/lib/vanilla.js:312:16)
    at buildBody (/path/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-classes/lib/vanilla.js:244:10)
    at run (/path/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-classes/lib/vanilla.js:151:10)
    at PluginPass.ClassExpression (/path/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-classes/lib/index.js:63:60)
    at newFn (/path/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/visitors.js:293:19)
    at NodePath._call (/path/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/path/context.js:74:18)
    at NodePath.call (/path/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/path/context.js:46:17)
 @ ./app/js/components/Convictions/Options.react.js 29:22-55
```

Again this works fine in a repository but not in the other!
I'm currently trying to understand if it is connected to ES2015 transpilation.

Comment: Actually I fixed it! 
In my SectorsSliders I was calling directly the setInterval function. Like this:
    `clearInterval(this.interval);`

It turned out that I should have done:

    `this.clearInterval.bind(this,this.interval);`

A stupid error! But I still don't get why it was working on my original repo..